# how to link python static library with my c++ program

Tags: python

I am implementing a C++ program that uses python/C++ Extensions. As of now I am explicitly linking my program to python static library I compiled. I am wondering is there any way to link my program with system installed python(i mean the default python installation that comes with linux)

Answer (score 20):

Yes. There is a command line utility called `python-config`:

```
Usage: /usr/bin/python-config [--prefix|--exec-prefix|--includes|--libs|--cflags|--ldflags|--help]
```

For linkage purposes, you have to invoke it with `--ldflags` parameter. It will print a list of flags you have to pass to the linker (or `g++`) in order to link with system installed python libraries:

```
$ python-config --ldflags
-L/usr/lib/python2.6/config -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lpython2.6
```

It also can give you flags to compilation with `--cflags` parameter:

```
$ python-config --cflags
-I/usr/include/python2.6 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
```

Say you have a test program in `test.cpp` file, then you can do something like this in order to compile and link:

```
g++ $(python-config --cflags) -o test $(python-config --ldflags) ./test.cpp
```

That will link your program with shared libraries. If you want to go static, you can pass `-static` option to the linker. But that will link with all static stuff, including a runtime. If you want to go just with static python, you have to find those libraries yourself. One of the option is to parse `python-config --ldflags` output and look for libraries with `.a` extensions. But I'd rather stick to all dynamic or all static.

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Vlad, Thank you so much for the response.. but unfortunately I am not seeing any python-config tool in /usr/bin/ I am on Fedora13. Do you think it could depend on platform??

Comment: Do you have a python development RPM installed? This is a part of SDK I think. I have it on both Ubuntu 10.4 and Fedora 12. You just probably don't have required package installed.

Comment: hey.. Thanks!! found it after installing python-devel from package manager using 'sudo yum install python-devel'