# Import error when using Python 3.6 in C++

Tags: cmake

I'm getting the below error when trying to call a python script from a C++ program

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./../resources/im-to-text.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

PIL/pillow is installed on my system, and I can directly run the Python script without issues. The issue seems to be the version of Python and the libraries included by CMake has some difference from the main version used on my Windows machine, and so PIL isn't there for the script to use. I chose to use a separate Python component for the image processing since I feel much more comfortable with PIL than with libpng, so I would prefer suggestions that keep the use of a separate Python component rather than just doing it all in C++. My C++ code to run it is

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "LOADING IMAGE" << endl;

    //Use python to parse the image
    string dataSource = "simple";
    string command = R"(python ./../resources/im-to-text.py )";
    command += dataSource;
    system(command.c_str());

    //Unrelated code here

    command = R"(python ./../resources/text-to-im.py )";
    command += dataSource;
    system(command.c_str());

    cout << "DONE" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My CMakeLists file is currently

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(picture_maze_solver)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp src/GraphNode.cpp src/GraphNode.h src/GraphEdge.cpp src/GraphEdge.h src/FileParser.cpp src/FileParser.h)
set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 3.6)
set(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE C:\\Users\\MY_USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python.exe)
find_package( PythonInterp 3.6 REQUIRED )
set(PYTHON_LIBRARY C:\\Users\\MY_USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\libs\\python36.lib)
find_package(PythonLibs 3.6 REQUIRED)
include_directories ( ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable(picture_maze_solver ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

It seems to be related to the StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842915/compile-c-with-embedded-python-using-cmake-import-error), but I'm not sure how the jump from Python 2 to Python 3 would affect this, and I can't find any files with the `.so` file extension in my Python folder. Additionally, the fix proposed of adding the `dlopen` call didn't change anything for my build, though I might have done it incorrectly since I couldn't find and `.so` files to reference. Is there a way to force CMake to use a Python version based on a Windows file path so it can find PIL?

Comment: what is the output of `where python` I think your binary will use the `set PATH` to find python also you don't need python at all in your CMake since your are just doing some system exec. Did you try the opposite create a c++ library wrapped it in python (e.g. SWIG) then call everything from python since you're more comfortable with python...

Comment: Why do you set 'PYTHON_EXECUTABLE' and 'PYTHON_LIBRARY' before calling their respective `find_package`s ? Also: is PIL installed for Python3? I.e. did you run `pip3 install PIL` (or `pip3 install pillow`)?