# Makefile compiles binary, not executable

Tags: python, c++, macos, makefile, g++

When i run the executable after make, bash raise following error:

```
$ ./prog 
-bash: ./prog: cannot execute binary file
```

My makefile:

```
CC = g++ -std=c++11
LDFLAGS = -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle
OBJ = main.o datetime.o logger.o WeatherApi.o tinyxml2.o tflower.o tservo.o


prog: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $<

clean:
    rm -r *.o
```

What did i wrong?

---

**Update 2:**

Thanks for your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191350/makefile-compiles-binary-not-executable#comment83363894_48191350) SergayA. After link python with the help of [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891202/how-to-link-python-static-library-with-my-c-program) it works.

---

**Update 1:**

I removed the `-undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle` flag after some comments so i got problems with Python. To use Python.h i set the environment variable to this path:
`CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/`

```
2 warnings generated.
g++ -std=c++11 -c datetime.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -c logger.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -c WeatherApi.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -c tinyxml2.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -c tflower.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -c tservo.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -o prog main.o datetime.o logger.o WeatherApi.o tinyxml2.o tflower.o tservo.o 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyDict_GetItemString", referenced from:
      WeatherApi::SayHelloWorld() in WeatherApi.o
      WeatherApi::GetAirTemperature() in WeatherApi.o
  "_PyErr_Print", referenced from:
      WeatherApi::WeatherApi(char*, char*) in WeatherApi.o
      WeatherApi::GetAirTemperature() in WeatherApi.o
  "_PyImport_Import", referenced from:
      WeatherApi::WeatherApi(char*, char*) in WeatherApi.o
  "_PyModule_GetDict", referenced from:
      WeatherApi::WeatherApi(char*, char*) in WeatherApi.o
  "_PyObject_CallObject", referenced from:
      WeatherApi::SayHelloWorld() in WeatherApi.o
      WeatherApi::GetAirTemperature() in WeatherApi.o
  "_PyString_AsString", referenced from:
      WeatherApi::GetAirTemperature() in WeatherApi.o
  "_PyString_FromString", referenced from:
      WeatherApi::WeatherApi(char*, char*) in WeatherApi.o
      WeatherApi::GetAirTemperature() in WeatherApi.o
  "_PyTuple_New", referenced from:
      WeatherApi::GetAirTemperature() in WeatherApi.o
  "_PyTuple_SetItem", referenced from:
      WeatherApi::GetAirTemperature() in WeatherApi.o
  "_Py_Finalize", referenced from:
      WeatherApi::~WeatherApi() in WeatherApi.o
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
      WeatherApi::WeatherApi(char*, char*) in WeatherApi.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [prog] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you execute after building manually, i.e. with a handwritten commandline instead of via make?

Comment: What does `file prog` tell you?

Comment: yes, i can build manually.

Comment: @SergeyA do you mean the content? Starts with: ???x__TEXT??__text__TEXT?XS??__stubs__TEXT?c???__stub_helper__TEXTth?th?__gcc_except_tab__TEXT<l<l__cstring__TEXT?ti?t__const__TEXT`z?`z__unwind_info__TEXT

Comment: @raze92, no, I mean the exact command output

Comment: prog: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64

Comment: You should know, then explain, why do you use `-undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle`. So **edit your question** to improve it and add more explanation about your `Makefile`. If you don't know why you use that you need to remove it from your `Makefile`. Most programs don't need such extra linker flags.

Comment: Do you have "execute" permission flag set for your file?

Comment: Reacting you your edit: you need specify Python runtime library to the linker as well.

Comment: @raze92, please do not update your question in such a way that it fundamentally changes it or adds a completely new dimension, as you did with your update 1.  If you discover a new problem after the question you asked is answered, and if your research on that new problem is unavailing, then the right thing to do is to pose a new, separate question about the new problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What did i wrong?

Since you apparently wanted a program that you can execute directly, what you did wrong was to specify [the `-bundle` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Darwin-Options.html#Darwin-Options) to g++.  This instructs it that the output should be a Mach-o *bundle format* file.  Such files are not directly executable.  They can be loaded into another program at runtime via the system's dynamic linking functions, which can be used to implement plugins and similar program features.  Remove this option.

The `-undefined dynamic_lookup` looks suspicious, too.  I'm guessing that you copied that and the `-bundle` option from some other Makefile.  If you don't know what it's there for then you ought to drop it, too.